# Insert new rows in a dataframe column equal to the number in a given row and fill it with 1's in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to insert rows in a data frame after verifying if the nnumber in that row is greater than 1 or not. if the number is greater than 1 than I want to remove that row and at it's place insert the same number of rows as was the number written in the previous row and fill those new rows with one while copying other values in other colums and keeping them as same.
I have tried:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['Dead females']> 1 ,True, False )
df[:50]
```

Beginning of dataframe looks like:

[image]

Rows with value greater than 1 looks like as in row 46:

[image]

what I wanted is for eg. at 46 where the condition is true at third column i.e. is greater than 1 then insert 2 rows each with 1's inserted. Iterate and do this for the whole dataframe.

Comment: Plese provide a [mre] especially a copy paste example, pictures only for understanding not to provide data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age in days':[45, 46, 47],
                    'Dead females':[0,2,1],
                    'Censored':[0,1,0],
                    'Fly Line':['CS 0.5 LS F','CS 0.5 LS F','CS 0.5 LS F']})

df
   Age in days  Dead females    Censored       Fly Line
0           45             0           0    CS 0.5 LS F
1           46             2           1    CS 0.5 LS F
2           47             1           0    CS 0.5 LS F
```

Now convert `Dead females` to a list as follows:

```
df['Dead females'] = df['Dead females'].apply(lambda x : [1]*x)
```

Then use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on that column:

```
df = df.explode('Dead females', ignore_index = True)
```

Then replace `np.nan` in that column to `0` to get the final df.

```
df['Dead females'].replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
```

**Output:**

```
    Age in days Dead females    Censored       Fly Line
0            45            0           0    CS 0.5 LS F
1            46            1           1    CS 0.5 LS F
2            46            1           1    CS 0.5 LS F
3            47            1           0    CS 0.5 LS F
```

Comment: Thank you so much!